# AngularJS: Good practice - where put the templates? (factory / directives)

Tags: angularjs, templates, factory, directive

I'm wondering which practice is better?

1. Put the templates inside the directives?
2. Put the templates into the factory, inject this factory inside the directives and use the templates from factory?

For better understanding:

Example 1:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('myDirective1', function () {
    var myTemplate = '<div> 
                         //a looooot of HTML
                      </div>';

    return {
        template: myTemplate
    };
});
```

Example 2:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('myDirective2', ['templateFactory', function (templateFactory) {

    return {
        template: templateFactory.myTemplate
    };
}]);


angular.module('myApp').factory('templateFactory', function () {
    var Template = '<div> 
                      //a looooot of HTML
                    </div>';
    return {
        myTemplate = Template
    }
});
```

> Consider that I have for example **20 directives and each of them have
> its own template** - put all the templates inside the factory or leave
> them in directives?
>
> Which way is better for use, better for read,
> better for everything?

I simplified these directives for reading and better understanding the problem, but in my project the directives have a lot of stuff inside (controllers, scopes, etc)

Comment: factory would be low on the list of ways to do it. Other ways are `$templateCache`, script tag templates, server file etc

Comment: I would recommend keeping templates external to the directive and use `templateUrl: /path/to/tmpl` Editing templates later on in the `template` string can become cumbersome.  I would definitely make use of the `$templateCache` as @charlietfl said above.

Answer (score 1):

What i would do is put the templates in separate files under the resources.

In the directives use

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('myDirective1', function () {
    return {
        templateUrl: "path/to/the/template.html"
    };
});
```

If you are providing your directives to others outside your application then i would just put them in the directives. like so.

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('myDirective1', function () {
    return {
        template: "<div> ... </div>"
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using this file structure and I am very convinced of it ;)

```
js
 |- controllers
 |- directives
   |- ExampleDirective
     |- ExampleDirective.js
     |- ExampleDirective.html
   |- ...
 |- filters
 |- services
```

Then just use your *directive* with `templateUrl` like so:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('ExampleDirective', function () {
    return {
        templateUrl: '[myPath]/ExampleDirective.html'
    };
});
```

Comment: structure makes modularity hard to accomplish. Although this was the way seed projects started, it didn't take long to realize it wasn't very scale able

Comment: Well, I think it depends on how big (in terms of module variety) your app is. If you have just a few (logically divided) modules and your focus is on controller and template logic, this might be the right choice.

Answer (score 1):

After 2 years of struggling with AngularJS we came to a module oriented structure, where each module could be independent component and includes directives, services, templates and also tests.

Also we define 2 common modules: **Data Layer** and **UI Library**.

[image]

Comment: After struggling with different setups, I've also come to this conclusion.  To separate out components into their own folder with their own directives, services, controllers, etc and have shared/common folder for all components to use that also has a directive, service, filter, etc folder.

Comment: I like the modularity attempt but how do you provide cross-access for filters, services, etc.? Just by adding 2 *messy* common modules?

Comment: it depends on your project architecture. and indeed what I call "Data Layer" could be quite messy